# Is there a way to programmatically detect UI components of an Android app?

Tags: android, user-interface, components

I want to take the source, or preferably just the .apk file, and find out all the UI components of an Android application (ex. XML layout).

Is there any way to accomplish this task?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [apktool](http://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/) or [APK Manager](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=695701) (that uses apktool) for reverse engineering.

And [Hierarchy Viewer](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/hierarchy-viewer.html) is an SDK tool for layout debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Layoutopt with the Android SDK will let you do this.  You can connect to a device/emulator with the app in question running and see how its screens are laid out and such.